# How do I get a layout exactly from my PSD

Tags: html, css, xhtml

What I have done ? http://jsfiddle.net/ref9g/

What I want it looks like? https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWRuC.png

Let me know the best trick how to get it done ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trick?

One trick might be to float the children of the wrapper to the left. You may need [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) to make sure the backgrounds work out, though.

Another trick would be `display: table` and `display: table-cell` and the like, though old IEs do not support settings those display modes via CSS, so a float fallback may still be necessary.